# how to dynamically insert random value to a column in excel through pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below two functions:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import string

def random_alphanumeric(length, hyphen_interval=4):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    random_value = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return '-'.join(random_value[i:i + hyphen_interval] for i in range(0, len(random_value), hyphen_interval))




def process_excel(xl_input_file, xl_output_file):
    df = pd.read_excel(xl_input_file)
    df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'], errors='coerce')
    updated_rows = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        updated_rows.append(pd.DataFrame([row], columns=df.columns))
        if row['Value'] != 0:
            new_row = row.copy()
            new_row['Value'] = -row['Value']
            updated_rows.append(pd.DataFrame([new_row], columns=df.columns))
            new_row['ID'] = random_alphanumeric(16, hyphen_interval=4)
            new_row['gla'] = '2100-abc'
    updated_df = pd.concat(updated_rows, ignore_index=True)
    updated_df.to_excel(xl_output_file, index=False)


# Example usage
xl_input_file = 'input.xlsx'
xl_output_file = 'updated_file.xlsx'
process_excel(xl_input_file, xl_output_file)
```

Functionality of functions

```
1- I have an excel file where I have `ID`, `gla`, `value`, and `4 more columns`.
2- The value has some numeric data which could be negative or positive. i.e. for any row there could be 23245, or -7989 for example. 
3- The `process_excel()` function is suppose to convert corresponding 
 `positive value to negative`, and `vice versa`. i.e. for the example given in point 2, `for 23245` there will be `-23245`, and `for -7989` it would be `7989`. The function is doing the conversion.
```

My challenge is that I also wanted to enter some random generated value for `ID` column and a hard coded value for `gla` column. I have written a reusable function called `random_alphanumeric()` that generates a alphanumeric value, and I have also called this function within `process_excel()`. But it doesn't seems to have any effect  in the new excel file that is generated. Please suggest what could be the issue in my code.

Note: for rest of 4 columns will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain why you need to loop through the rows?

In your example above, `new_row` is a copy, but never makes it back into `updated_df` after the ID is assigned.

You can do this without looping I think:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import string


def random_alphanumeric(length, hyphen_interval=4):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    random_value = "".join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return "-".join(
        random_value[i : i + hyphen_interval]
        for i in range(0, len(random_value), hyphen_interval)
    )


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Value": [10, 0, 0, 22, -5],
    }
)

df["Value"] = -pd.to_numeric(df["Value"], errors="coerce")
df["ID"] = df.apply(lambda x: random_alphanumeric(16, hyphen_interval=4), axis=1)
df["gla"] = "2100-abc"

print(df)
```

output:

```
   Value                   ID       gla
0    -10  Q1T2-0CxA-er3b-Zi5U  2100-abc
1      0  I7LL-bj56-uInj-aRpl  2100-abc
2      0  53qZ-CSAE-Cwsq-Fkbk  2100-abc
3    -22  3g6V-GYPM-VwAG-qKwd  2100-abc
4      5  Vbn1-EINt-A8c8-k89w  2100-abc
```